# Parenting this in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the following code works without any luck, and I can't see a clear solution on how to do it.

```
export default {
    model: null,
    set: function (data) {
        this.model = data
    },
    account: {
        update: function (data) {
            this.model.account = data
        }
    }
}
```

My issue here is that `account.update` fails because `this.model` does not exists. I suspect that the sub object gets a new `this`, hence my issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried the alternative here :

```
export default (function () {
    let model = null
    function set (data) {
        this.model = data // I also tried without the `this.` but without any luck too
    },

    function updateAccount(data) {
        this.model.account = data
    }

    return {
        'model': model,
        'set': set,
        'account': {
            'update': updateAccount
        }
    }
})()
```

But apparently the same rule applies.

Maybe it's worth noting that I'm using Babel to compile ES6 down to ES5 javascript.

Comment: ES6 is "actual JavaScript", it just isn't supported fully by all of the browsers yet. (Large parts of it are supported by certain browsers.) I think you mean you are transpiling it down to ES5...

Comment: Indeed! I updated my message accordingly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `this` refers (in this case) to the window object. Reference the object itself like this:

```
let myModel = {
    model: null,
    set: function (data) {
        myModel.model = data // reference myModel instead of this
    },
    account: {
        update: function (data) {
            myModel.model.account = data // reference myModel instead of this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot to mention something, I get myModel from `export default {}`, I updated the snippet accordingly

Comment: @CyrilN. You don't have to export the object directly. You create the object like in this answer and then `export default myModel;`.

Answer (score 1):

I would take an approach similar to your alternative solution. There is however no need to wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), ES2015 modules are self-contained; you don't need an IIFE for encapsulation.

```
let model = null,
  set = (data) => {
    model = data;
  },
  updateAccount = (data) => {
    if (!model) {
      throw('model not set');
    }
    model.account = data;
  };

export default {
    model,
    set,
    account: {
        update: updateAccount
    }
};
```

Since you are already using Babel, I also used [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and the new [shorthand properties](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html) to make the code a little shorter/readable.